# Changing the colour of energy bars depending on their values?

Tags: java, progress-bar

I created this method to check the value in my progress bar. It works as expected when it is decreasing, i.e. it turns red, yellow and orange. But when I increase the value the colour doesn't update. So when it's below 25 and turns red, it remains that colour when I increase the value of the energy bar. What am I doing wrong here? thanks in advance.

```
public void checkEnergyBar(JProgressBar EnergyBar){
    if(EnergyBar.getValue()<25){
        EnergyBar.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }else if(EnergyBar.getValue()<51){
        EnergyBar.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    }else if(EnergyBar.getValue()<76){
        EnergyBar.setForeground(Color.orange);
    }else if(EnergyBar.getValue()<101){
        EnergyBar.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    }

     EnergyBar.repaint();

}
```

I made these changes, and still no joy.

```
public void checkEnergyBar(JProgressBar EnergyBar){
    if(getEnergy()<26 ){
        EnergyBar.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }else if(getEnergy()<51 || getEnergy()>26){
        EnergyBar.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    }else if(getEnergy()<76 || getEnergy()>51){
        EnergyBar.setForeground(Color.orange);
    }else if(getEnergy()<101 || getEnergy()>76){
        EnergyBar.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    }

     EnergyBar.repaint();

}
```

Comment: The `checkEnergyBar()` method definitely doesn't depend on direction of value change (because it doesn't store any previous values), so there is some mistake in caller code.

Comment: The energy bar starts off at 100, and as the energy is decreasing, all the if statements function. It just doesn't do the same in reverse as I increase the value.

Comment: I do understand what you're asking, but I'm sure problem is in another place. My comment above clarifies why.

Comment: I had some situations that I had to update the progress bar properties througth a thread. Try using a SwingWorker.

Comment: In theory it sounds like a really simple thing to do. I'm surprised that the progress bar is so limited.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think that the JProgressBar is bugged. I have my own, more customizable way of making a progress bar.

Instead of using the pre-made JProgressBar, use the original way of displaying graphics: Canvas

Create a subclass of canvas, then override the paint method, add variables to represent the color and value, and add a setValue method. In the paint method, set the color based on the value, setForeground(color),  then simply use the graphics argument to paint a rectangle(0,0,value,getHeight()).

That is personally how I would make a progress bar. This also has the advantage of:
A) You could add a border & background color to the canvas, just like a progress bar
B) You could use graphics.paintImage and scale/crop an image to the correct size

Hopefully this helped with your progress bar :)